# Give access to certain Google Cloud Buckets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

Is there a way to define an IAM policy or custom role to allow access to certain cloud storage buckets for a project instead of having to add the user for each individual bucket?

Comment: Edit your question and include details on how you have access control configured for the bucket. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom role as per your requirement and write a shell script to grant a role to a member.

Example -

```
  #!/bin/bash
  members=(member1 member2 member3)
  for i in “${members[@]}”
  do 
        gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding my-project \
        --member=user:$i --role=role-id 
  done
```

The above script will bind the role to members.

gcloud command -

```
gcloud group add-iam-policy-binding resource \
    --member=member --role=role-id
```

- Group: The gcloud tool group for the resource you want to update. For
  example, you can use projects or organizations.
- resource: The name of the resource.
- Member: An identifier for the member,  An identifier for the member,
  For example,  user:my-user@example.com/.